# Should I run Windows Virtual Machines on a Windows or Linux host?

Tags: windows, linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have currently have a PC with 16GB of RAM. I will be running multiple virtual machines using VirtualBox.

Would I get the best performance from running the VMs on a Linux host, or a Windows host?

If Linux is best can anyone recommend a distribution to use?

Comment: Pick the host OS based on your daily needs when you're not running VMs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, as long as the OS is 64-bit I don't think it really matters. It's down to personal preference. I've ran VirtualBox on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 and have not seen much of a performance difference. One question is what processor do you have, and is it enough to run enough Virtual Machines to take advantage of 16GB of RAM?

Comment: thanks for you answer, I will am using an i5 3.3 GHz 2500k

Comment: It depend of what you want to do. If you want an hypervisor type 1 then Virtualbox is useless, and you machine will work fine. But if you want to try hypervisor type 2, then you can try out virtualbox, and I would says, both linux or windows work fine with hypervisor type 2

Answer (score 6):

I would probably recommend using a minimalist Linux distro, perhaps a server version with XFCE or similar desktop, running your virtualisation software. The less load on your host, the better. :). As for a distro, probably Ubuntu Server 10.04 for me personally, and if you're not used to package management, the Ubuntu one (apt) is really easy to use.

Hope that helps :).

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with virtual machines using suse 11.2, 11.4 and also run it on debian lenny. I would recommend that your host is a linux box due to the fact that it can handle the load and is stable. I would say linux is a better server os. so go with any linux distro you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a linux guru, I'd recommend using Windows as a host. This is because:

1-Since hardware vendors usually target Windows, it has a better driver support. And it is very important for the system that host machine recognizes all the hardware properly. For example if the host machine can not use the graphics card properly then no guests (either linux or windows) will.

2-Windows games won't work properly on a virtual machine.

3-if you have an android device, windows has a better mtp support. On linux, with big files such as movies it sucks.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't really be too much difference in performance, perhaps besides the drivers available for the host's video so proper acceleration can be utilized. I have used both VMWare on Windows and Linux (as well as VBox more recently) and I have not really noticed any pertinent differences.

As someone else mentioned, the only obvious benefit would be that linux has a much smaller overhead to run as compared to Windows. So you should technically have more resources free to run more virtual machines. In regards to linux distro it shouldn't really matter, but Ubuntu anywhere from Lucid Lynx (10.04) forward would be a good starting point.